# Can i delay a specific part of a program?

Tags: java, swing

Can i delay a specific part of a program without delaying the whole thread? e.g

```
pcard3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("resources/images/cards/"+playerCard3+".gif"));
```

Can i wait 5 seconds before setting the icon of the `JLabel`?

Comment: You would need to create a new thread for this.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest using [Swing Timers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for such tasks (either one time or recurring tasks).

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setIcon(...);
    }
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is for. For more detail, see the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Comment: I will clarify a bit and say this is _exactly_ what SwingWorker is for.

Comment: How do you implement the 5 second delay with SwingWorker? Isn't a Swing Timer a better fit?

Comment: @Paul Cager, simply invoke `Thread.sleep(5000)`, although you're right, a Swing Timer is definitely the better option. unfortunately, `SwingWorker` came to mind first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not render the UI components in a separate thread so that if you put a 5 second delay in that it doesn't affect the rest of program.

Comment: As long as you update on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).