# Is it possible to delay multiple parts of a thread with a gui?

Tags: java

Is it possible to delay multiple parts of a thread with a gui?
Like setting a JLabel

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Could you give a more concrete example?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something like "setting the text of a label after 3 seconds" you would have to create some timer and update the text of the label upon timeout.

---

**Edit**: Reading your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494059/can-i-delay-a-specific-part-of-a-program) makes it slightly more clear.

You would have to use to what [Howard tells you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494059/can-i-delay-a-specific-part-of-a-program/6494391#6494391) for each statement, *or* bundle all the to-be-delayed statements in the `actionPerformed` method.